# T/SQL: Format results of SELECT on XML stored as nvarchar(max)

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, nlog

I am not sure why, but our nLog configuration is now stored as an nvarchar(max) column in a table. With a standard SELECT on the column, I get output like:

```
&lt;variable name=&quot;HeaderLayout&quot;....
```

I have tried using "FOR XML AUTO", as well as a series of REPLACE functions to get nice, pretty XML output from this column. Option A doesn't automatically cast the replacement markers to < or >, option B is really clumsy. Can someone please recommend a good why to retrieve the configuration as formatted XML?

As a bonus, I'd like to be able to take the formatted XML, make a change and then INSERT with a minimum of effort, but for now, I'd just settle for being able to make the SELECT results more readable.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First cast the value to XML. That will create an XML with your entire XML as a single value.
Then you get that value from the XML using the value function and finally you cast the fetched value back to XML.

Here is some code using a table variable you can test on.

```sql
declare @T table
(
  Col nvarchar(max)
)

insert into @T(Col)
values('&lt;root&gt;&lt;item ID="1"&gt;textvalue&lt;/item&gt;&lt;/root&gt;') 

select cast(cast(T.Col as xml).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') as xml) as XMLCol
from @T as T
```

Result:

```
XMLCol
-------------------------------------------
<root><item ID="1">textvalue</item></root>
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the idea. Can I make this work using a SELECT statement instead of the actual text? For instance:

insert into @T(Col)
values((SELECT data FROM configuration where id = 4)) 

I tried this and get an empty column back from the final SELECT. Not sure if there's an adjustment I need to make.

Comment: @Purple yes, of course. The table variable is there just to give you something to play with. You want to use the last select. Replace the table with whatever your table is called and the column name with what column name you have.

Answer (score 0):

Try `FOR XML AUTO, TYPE`. And can you provide an example of your query?

Comment: SELECT data
FROM Configuration
where id = 4

Comment: Using "FOR XML AUTO, TYPE" doesn't seem to be any better. 

However, "FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENT" at least breaks the results into nice rows (intsted of one long text string). The lt; &amp; and gt; literals still appear as text, not the actual symbol you'd expect in an XML file.